# Azure Website Orchard Update

Tags: orchardcms, azure-web-app-service

so I have several websites running on Azure. One has its own instance, and I know I can upgrade that by just updating the code. But quite a few websites I have are Azure Websites. I installed Orchard from the gallery. Orchard 1.6 has just been released, not on the gallery yet, but will be soon I assume. Is there a way of upgrading my existing websites to 1.6 when it is released?

Or do I have to like ftp the latest code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure web sites are like a regular hosting plan: you upgrade the same way you would anywhere else (WebDeploy, FTP, Git...). See http://docs.orchardproject.net/Documentation/Upgrading-a-site-to-a-new-version-of-Orchard